# command \pagenumbering can't change numbers style i

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, babel, arabic, roman-numerals

I want to use Roman numbers and Arabic  numbers in my thesis. the total language of the document is Arabic and  I use command `\pagenumbering` to change page number's style. I tried most of the solutions that add command `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` but it doesn't work. this is **MWC** :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic, english]{babel}

\renewcommand{\I}[1]        {\if@farsi\FarsiEncoding\else\ArabicEncoding\fi\textLR{#1}}%
\renewcommand{\EI}[1]{\textLR{\FarsiEncoding  \textLR{#1}}}%
\renewcommand \thechapter {\textLR{\arabic{chapter}}}

\TOCLanguage{arabic} % arabic is the main language 
\newcommand\lr[1]{\textLR{#1}}
\newcommand\rl[1]{\textRL{#1}}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{arabic}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter*{الملخص}
الملخص العربي 
\chapter*{\lr{Abstract}}
    \textLR{ English abstract\ldots}
\chapter*{كلمة الشكر}
نص باللغة العربية   
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{تجريب}
نص باللغة العربية\\

\end{document}
```

using the method suggested by @egreg the problem of page numbering has been **solved** but it changes the style of the  **table of contents**, where the numbers changes into arabi-indi coding ?So is there any way to fix this problem?
this is the method suggested by @egreg :

```
\makeatletter
\def\ps@plain{\ps@empty\SAV@ps@plain}
\makeatletter
\pagestyle{plain}
```

and this is the result of this change:
[image: result after redefine <code>plain</code>]

By redefining command `\pagenumbering` as @egreg the problem of **toc** arabi-inidi coding has been solved and this is the suggested redefinition :

```
\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\protect\textLR{\roman{page}}}
```

then when arabic numbers is needed

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\protect\textLR{\arabic{page}}}
```

and this is the result :
[image]

Comment: I also tried to put command `\cleardoublepage` befor `\pagenumbering{roman}` but it doesn't work.

Comment: removing command `TOClanguage{arabic} `dosen't solve the problem

Comment: I also tried to define a new counter and change it's style and it's value manually but it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried to redefine the counter `thepage` and then change it's style but also it doesn't work.

Comment: by redefine  the `plain`  page style the problem of page numbering has been solved but the suggested method changes the style of the table of contents? is there any way to solve this problem?@egreg

Comment: the problem of **toc**  arabi-inidi code has been solved after redefining command  `\pagenumbering` as @egreg suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plain` page style is redefined to always give `\number\c@page`.

You can revert this decision made by `arabicore.sty`. But I'm afraid you have to supplement the `\pagenumbering` declaration.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,arabic]{babel}

\renewcommand{\I}[1]{\if@farsi\FarsiEncoding\else\ArabicEncoding\fi\textLR{#1}}%
\renewcommand{\EI}[1]{\textLR{\FarsiEncoding\textLR{#1}}}%
\renewcommand\thechapter{\textLR{\arabic{chapter}}}

\TOCLanguage{arabic} % arabic is the main language 
\newcommand\lr[1]{\textLR{#1}}
\newcommand\rl[1]{\textRL{#1}}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@plain{\ps@empty\SAV@ps@plain}
\makeatletter
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\protect\textLR{\roman{page}}}

\chapter*{الملخص}
الملخص العربي 

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\chapter*{Abstract}
English abstract
\end{otherlanguage}

\chapter*{كلمة الشكر}
نص باللغة العربية   

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\protect\textLR{\arabic{page}}}

\chapter{تجريب}
نص باللغة العربية\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: could you please explain the differences between the following methods: the first one is what you define : `\def\ps@plain{\ps@empty\SAV@ps@plain} ` and the other is define the counter `\thepage` and the change it's style, how t these methods are work?  where could I find more information on this topic.

Comment: when I redefine `plain`  the table of contents change it's style ,so what is the problem?

Comment: @AhmadHafez Fixed in the new version.

Comment: after redefining  `\pagenumbering` as you suggested and compile twice the problem of **toc** is solved