# changing page numbering style from Arabic to roman doesn't work

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, babel, arabic, roman-numerals

I want to use Roman numbers and Arabic numbers in my thesis. the main language of the document is Arabic and I use command `\pagenumbering` to change page number's style. I tried most of the solutions that add command `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` but it doesn't work, however  redefining `plain` page style as in 
[command \pagenumbering can't change numbers style i](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458763/command-pagenumbering-cant-change-numbers-style-i) changes from Arabic to roman numbers but it affects **toc** in bad way and here the details of **toc** [Table of contents** : how to change redefine commands \@tocrmarg and \@pnumwidth for different levels (chapter ,sec,..)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458973/table-of-contents-how-to-change-redefine-commands-tocrmarg-and-pnumwidth).

The main language of the document is **Arabic**. how can I change page's numbers from Arabic 
 to roman without redefine 'plain' page style . this is MWC :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic, english]{babel}

\renewcommand{\I}[1]        {\if@farsi\FarsiEncoding\else\ArabicEncoding\fi\textLR{#1}}%
\renewcommand{\EI}[1]{\textLR{\FarsiEncoding  \textLR{#1}}}%
\renewcommand \thechapter {\textLR{\arabic{chapter}}}

\TOCLanguage{arabic} % arabic is the main language 
\newcommand\lr[1]{\textLR{#1}}
\newcommand\rl[1]{\textRL{#1}}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{arabic}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter*{الملخص}
الملخص العربي 
\chapter*{\lr{Abstract}}
    \textLR{ English abstract\ldots}
\chapter*{كلمة الشكر}
نص باللغة العربية   
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{تجريب}
نص باللغة العربية\\

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using an old method of writing Arabic with a lot of problems to insert packages   you can use `xelatex`.

Here your example using `polyglossia` ( which calls internally the package `bidi` for adaptation of many  com­monly-used pack­ages to right to left writing )

```
% compile with xelatex 
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}


\chapter*{الملخص}

الملخص العربي 

\chapter*{Abstract}

    \LR{ English abstract\ldots}

\chapter*{كلمة الشكر}

نص باللغة العربية   

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{تجريب}

نص باللغة العربية\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: when using your code it allows gives me errors in  `ployglossia.sty` like :**Undefined control sequence. `\ExplSyntaxOn`**

Comment: You need to update your TeX distribution.
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution